# How do I unsync all apple devices for text?

Tags: iphone, ipad, messages

How do I unsync my iphone messages so that those do not go to my ipad.  I have unclicked the email address associated with my ipad on my iphone.   Is there something else I need to do so other people in the house do not see my text messages on the ipad?

Comment: Are you asking if changing the password on your AppleID will prevent all devices from receiving iMessage going forward?

Answer (score 1):

You want to (on your iPhone) open Settings, then go to **Messages -> Text Message Forwarding**, then uncheck your iPad

Comment: I don't see an option on my iphone 5S under messages for **Text Message Forwarding**. I see Send & Receive.

Comment: It's there. Go to http://www.aoole.com/ios/messages/ for more info.